# How to asaign lambda funcion in unordered_map with cpp?

Tags: c++, dictionary, lambda

Currently trying to learn c++, and I'm trying to make a "hunt the wumpus" application to help me learn. I am having trouble assigning a lambda function to an unordered_map in C++. My IDE is giving me the error
"Parameter type mismatch: Incompatible pointer types 'node *const' and 'node *(*)(node *)'"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
class node{
public:
    int title;
    node *adj[8];
    std::string desc;
}
...
bool shoot(node *player){
std::unordered_map<std::string, node*> adjLambda; //lambda to return *left, *up, etc

    for (int i; i < 8; i++){
        if (player->adj[i]->title != player->title){ //empty adjacencies points towards self
            adjLambda.insert(std::pair <std::string, node*> (std::to_string(player->adj[i]->title), [](node *n) { return n->adj[i];}));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your map holds `std::string` as keys and `node*` as values. A lambda is neither of those types, so why would you expect to be able to insert one into that map?

Comment: I'm more used to high level languages like python and java, and am very new new to c++. Do you mind me asking how to define a lambda?

Comment: What do you mean "define a lambda"? Regardless of what you write, your map will not hold anything else than the types it's declared to hold and a lambda will never be any of those types. If you want to hold a lambda in a map, make the map hold `std::function` objects - a lambda can be stored in those (assuming it take the right arguments and returns the right type to match the signature of the `std::function`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include `<functional>` and then store the value as a `std::function`:

```
void shoot(node *player){
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<node*(node*)>> adjLambda; //lambda to return *left, *up, etc

    for(int i{}; i < 8; i++){
        if(player->adj[i]->title != player->title){ //empty adjacencies points towards self
            adjLambda.insert(           // insert into the unordered map
                std::pair<              // pair to be inserted
                    std::string,        // key is a string
                    std::function<      // map entry is a function
                        node*(node*)    // function takes a node pointer and returns a node pointer
                    >
                >(
                    std::to_string(player->adj[i]->title),  // create a string to use as the key
                    [i](node *n) { return n->adj[i]; }      // lambda that takes a node pointer and returns another
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: might i ask what this is doing?
adjLambda.insert(std::pair <std::string, std::function<node*(node*)>>(STD::TO_STRING(PLAYER->ADJ[I]->TITLE), [I](node *n) { return n->adj[i]; }));

Comment: @12Bits There is quite a bit going on, so I've unpacked it a bit.

Comment: @wally `std::make_pair` will make it a lot shorter

Comment: @MihaylA.A Yes, true. [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) would also be a good option.

Comment: @wally would either function produce better performance, or should I even be concerning myself with performance at this point?

Comment: `emplace` will construct the members in place. As for performance, you could try different options and then benchmark the results to decide.